# Date picker Not Working on API 26

Tags: java, android

**this code**

```
Calendar calendarStart = Calendar.getInstance();
    startYear = calendarStart.get(Calendar.YEAR) + 543;
    startMonth = calendarStart.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    startDay = calendarStart.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - 7;

    dateStartPickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(
            AccountReportActivity.this, R.style.DatePicker,
            AccountReportActivity.this, startYear, startMonth, startDay);

    dateStartPickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calendarStart.getTimeInMillis());
    calendarStart.add(Calendar.YEAR, 543);
    dateStartPickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(calendarStart.getTimeInMillis());
```

this error code

```
 at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: timeInMillis must be between the values of getMinDate() and getMaxDate()
                                                                        at android.widget.DayPickerView.setDate(DayPickerView.java:307)
                                                                        at android.widget.DayPickerView.setDate(DayPickerView.java:286)
                                                                        at android.widget.DayPickerView.setDate(DayPickerView.java:275)
                                                                        at android.widget.DatePickerCalendarDelegate.onDateChanged(DatePickerCalendarDelegate.java:405)
                                                                        at android.widget.DatePickerCalendarDelegate.init(DatePickerCalendarDelegate.java:376)
                                                                        at android.widget.DatePicker.init(DatePicker.java:228)
                                                                        at android.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:133)
                                                                        at android.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:109)
                                                                        at com.splanet.aplaysellers.activity.report.AccountReportActivity.setUpCurrentStartDate(AccountReportActivity.java:103)
                                                                        at com.splanet.aplaysellers.activity.report.AccountReportActivity.initWidget(AccountReportActivity.java:75)
                                                                        at com.splanet.aplaysellers.activity.report.AccountReportActivity.onCreate(AccountReportActivity.java:51)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6980)
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
```

Please help me I try to solve the problem by various sources. It can not solve this problem.

Comment: are you use samsung device for testing this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `System.currentTimeMillis()`for Max date this will return current date in Milli Seconds . and for min use Calender.!
If you want your app to work Completely fine on each Android Version follow my Example Code .! [Date Picker Example](https://github.com/AtifAbbAsi19/Date-Picker-Example-)

```
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), onDateSet,
                year, month, day);

        // calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, Constants.DateAndMonth.CURRENT_DAY);//Current day
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
        // Set the Calendar new date as maximum date of date picker
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());

        // Subtract 90 days from Calendar updated date
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -Constants.DateAndMonth.LAST_NINETY_DAY);

        // Set the Calendar new date as minimum date of date picker
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            datePickerDialog.setTitle("");//Prevent Date picker from creating extra Title.!
        }
```

Comment: dateStartPickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calendarStart.getTimeInMillis());
calendarStart.add(Calendar.YEAR, 543);
dateStartPickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(calendarStart.getTimeInMillis());
remove these line.!

Comment: welcome @PhattarapongYodwiset thanks and do upvote .!

Answer (score -1):

set different min and max date to datepicker
Try this

```
Calendar calendarStart = Calendar.getInstance();
startYear = calendarStart.get(Calendar.YEAR);
startMonth = calendarStart.get(Calendar.MONTH);
startDay = calendarStart.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - 7;

dateStartPickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(
        AccountReportActivity.this, R.style.DatePicker,
        AccountReportActivity.this, startYear, startMonth, startDay);

dateStartPickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calendarStart.getTimeInMillis());
calendarStart.add(Calendar.YEAR, 543);
dateStartPickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(calendarStart.getTimeInMillis());
```

Comment: Run this code on 4.4 and it will crash  on setMinDate(calendarStart.getTimeInMillis())  due to calendarStart.getTimeInMillis() Have a look at mine example above thanks.!