# how to set a specific month or year for slection in datepicker?

Tags: android, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog

In my app i want user to choose date from last year like from 1st jan to 31st december 2016 i tried set mindate & maxdate ....

```
public static class LastYearBirthDatePicker extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        int lastYear = getCurrentYear()-1;
        Calendar min = Calendar.getInstance();
        min.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1);
        min.set(Calendar.MONTH,0);
        min.set(Calendar.YEAR,lastYear);
        dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(min.getTimeInMillis());
        Calendar max = Calendar.getInstance();
        max.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,31);
        max.set(Calendar.MONTH,11);
        max.set(Calendar.YEAR,lastYear);
        dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(max.getTimeInMillis());
        return dialog;
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {


    }
}
```

but is there any better option for setting a specific year only 
And i need same for specific month also like any month in 2016 (user can choose any day in a specific month)

Comment: Is this not working, or not working as expected?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46842365/date-picker-not-working-on-api-26/46843164?noredirect=1#comment80634619_46843164
have a look at my Answer.!

Answer (score 0):

You can Set Like this

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(2016, 01, 01);
cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);

int xxday = cal.get(Calendar.DATE);
int xxmonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int xxyear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

datepicker.init(xxyear, xxmonth, xxday, null);
```